# How to get textbox value using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium library for testing.

I have this little code:

```
Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver()
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("C:\Users\Amodio\Desktop\HTMLPage1.htm")
driver.FindElement(By.Id("30")).SendKeys("1234")
MsgBox(driver.FindElement(By.Id("30")).Text)
```

The problem is that, in the messagebox i cannot see the value of the control.

It can send keys correctly, but in the next line code cannot catch the value.

Comment: What kind of element is it? An `input`?

Answer (score 1):

Like what you said in your question title, you want to show textbox's `value`.

For textboxes, `element.GetAttribute("value")` is the one you want, rather than `element.Text`.

```
MsgBox(driver.FindElement(By.Id("30")).GetAttribute("value"))
```